# Markdown to PDF - illustration on wrong place

Tags: latex, markdown, pandoc, pdflatex

So when I convert a markdown File to a PDF the illustration is always on the wrong place...

Example:

.md

```
aaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaaaa

bbbbb bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb bbbbbbbbbbbb bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb bbbbbbbbb
bbbbbbbbbbbbb bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb bbbbbbbbbbbbb

![APPLE](apple.png)

ccccccccccc cccccccccccccccccccccccc ccccccccccc ccccccccccccccccccc
cccccccccccccccc ccccccccccc ccccccccccccccc ccccccccccccccccccccccc


ddddddddddd ddddddd ddddddd dddddddd ddddddddddd dddddd dddddddddddddd
dddd dddddd dddddddd ddddddddd ddddddddddddd dddddddddd dddddddddddddd
```

.pdf looks like this :

Page 1: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxQ9M.png

Page 2: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJOLo.png

The illustration should be between the bbb.. and ccc..

Comment: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101725/latex-figures-appear-before-text-in-pandoc-markdown